# avplayer plays video on simulator not on device?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

i am having issues with playing a video through url using **avplayer** and **avplayerviewcontroller**

it plays fine on simulator but doesnt work on device.
Is it a problem with the static ip i have been using as follows -

https://ipaddress(111.111.11.11:443)/mc/images/wall/small.mp4

same video from the following url plays fine on device

http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4

the code below i am using -

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4"];//@""];https://180.179.77.47:443/mc/images/wall/small.mp4
    AVAsset *videoAsset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:url];

    AVPlayerItem *item = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:videoAsset];
    playerVideo = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:url];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance]setCategory:AVAudioSessionModeMoviePlayback error:nil];
    movieController = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc]init];
    [movieController setAllowsPictureInPicturePlayback:YES];
    movieController.player = playerVideo;
    movieController.delegate = self;
    movieController.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;

    [self presentViewController:movieController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: can this link help? http://www.transcoding.dk/2012/09/22/making-a-h-264-for-the-web-stream-instantly/

Comment: If you are having the first video in your local environment then it will not play outside your network.When i try to click on the link its not playing in my machine because your video is in your internal network. If you play your video through simulator its working because your machine is connected to your internal network.There is nothing to do with avplayer. Make sure your device is connected to the local network or publish your video in uat environment and test it.It works fine.

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing the same issue short while ago, but just now observed that my device was on silent mode & hence it was running video without sound.

But it should not have happened. If I run YouTube app & plays video, it works fine even if device is on silent mode.

I found the answer. Following is the Swift 3 code. If you set the category to `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback` and if the device is on silent mode then the app plays video with sound.

If you set the category to `AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient`, and if you run the app on device with silent mode on, then the app will play the video without sound.

```
let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

do
{
   try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, with: .duckOthers)
}
catch
{
   print("AVAudioSession cannot be set")
}
```

Comment: Added this to a bare-bone Audio Sample app that was working on the simulator but not on device.

Answer (score 0):

I think your video and your device are not withing same network. Used common network for both or put it at remote location from where everyone can access it.

You can play video in simulator because your system (mac) is connected with common network on which video is available but i think you are using different network for mobile network.

Hope this will help :)